# Misleading error passing OsString to a func<T: ToString>, where does Display trait comes from?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, traits

Why does this function call:

```
use std::string::ToString;
use std::ffi::OsString;

fn len<T: ToString>(v: &T) -> usize {
    v.to_string().len()
}

fn main() {
    let text = OsString::from("Hello, world!");
    let tlen = len(&text);
    println!("len('{:?}') = {}", &text, tlen);
}
```

raise this compilation error:

```
<anon>:10:16: 10:19 error: the trait `core::fmt::Display` is not implemented for the type `std::ffi::os_str::OsString` [E0277]
<anon>:10     let tlen = len(&text);
                         ^~~
<anon>:10:16: 10:19 note: `std::ffi::os_str::OsString` cannot be formatted with the default formatter; try using `:?` instead if you are using a format string
<anon>:10     let tlen = len(&text);
                         ^~~
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

I know that the code is broken as `OsString` does not implement `ToString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [trait `ToString`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/string/trait.ToString.html) is [implemented by all types that implement `Display`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/551a74dddd84cf01440ee84148ebd18bc68bd7c8/src/libcollections/string.rs#L985) (and, in fact, only those types):

```
impl<T: fmt::Display + ?Sized> ToString for T {
    ...
```

So, when the compiler looks for an implementation of `ToString`, it ends up trying to look for one for `Display` and that's where the trait search fails for `OsString` (`Display` doesn't have the same sort of "blanket impl").